# Minimal Polynomials and Ker

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

$V$ a $K$-Vector space, dim$(V) < \infty, \quad\phi  \in \operatorname{End}(V) $

Let $a,b \in K[X] $ normed with $a \neq b\quad$,  $a \big|b \quad$and $\quad b\big|g_\phi $ where $g_\phi$ is the minimal polynomial of $\phi$.

(1)

Show $$Ker(a(\phi))\subsetneq Ker(b(\phi))$$

So since $a \big|b $ and $b\big|g_\phi $ we can write $b = a \cdot r$ and $g_\phi = b \cdot z , \quad z,r\in K[X]$ .

So $g_\phi  = b \cdot z = a \cdot r \cdot z = 0 \Longleftrightarrow a=0  \lor r=0 \lor z=0 \Longrightarrow Ker(a(\phi))\subsetneq Ker(b(\phi))$ ?

(2)

For $e \in \mathbb N $ and $p \in K[X] $ a Prime Polynomial with $g_\phi = p^e$ for  $e \in \mathbb N$ and $W_i = ker(p^i(\phi))$ for $i \geq 0$

Show $$W_0 = \{0\} \subsetneq W_1 \subsetneq W_2 ... \subsetneq W_e = V $$
 I didnt get far here.

Comment: I think it is very hard not to see that (2) is a trivial corollary of (1). But anyway, your proof of (1) hardly makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof of the *non-trivial* part of $(1)$, i.e. a proof that the inclusion is strict. For the sake of notation I denote the minimal polynomial by $g$.

Note that $0=(b \cdot \frac{g}{b})(\phi)$, i.e. $\frac{g}{b}(\phi)$ maps $V$ to $\operatorname{ker}b(\phi)$. If the inclusion would be an equality, we would deduce $(a \cdot \frac{g}{b})(\phi)=0$, i.e. the polynomial $\frac{ag}{b}$ annihilates $\phi$. But $\deg \frac{ag}{b} < \deg g$, contradiction!